# Emulation prevention bytes in MP4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, libavcodec

H.264 defines that a sequence of two zero bytes should be escaped by adding a '3' byte after the two zero bytes ("Emulation prevention").

Is this escaping rule correct also for the mp4 file format?

The question is followed by results of debugging ffmpeg. I've tried to open the following file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrdy8z96pohh7ah/live_video_fragment_1.mp4?dl=0

VLC plays it but ffmpeg not. ffmpeg shows a lot of error, the first one is  (with log level debug):

```
AVC: Consumed only 41 bytes instead of 796
```

Debugging into ffmpeg shows that it tries to parse the moof box within the H.264 decoder and fails on https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/h264.c#L312

When parsing the 4 bytes preceding the `traf` box (which indicates its size), it understands the "0 0 3" bytes as emulation prevention bytes and all the parsing gets out of order because of this.

So, is this a wrong behavior of ffmpeg (which should not understand it as emulation prevention)? Or the file contains an error and the bytes SHOULD be escaped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this escaping rule correct also for the mp4 file format?

Escaping is enabled for H264 content in MP4, but it should only be enabled for the H264 portions inside the MP4 container. So given that the traf box is part of the MP4 container format, not any of the H264 NAL units, it should not be unescaped. I'd file a [bug](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/) with FFmpeg.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure that this is an ffmpeg bug, maybe the file contains an error. For some reason ffmpeg thinks that the samples data starts at the beginning of the MOOF box, I guess that the file just missing a value for the start offset of data of the fragment. Still checking it. If you can tell me also which box should contains this start offset it will help very much. Thanks!

Comment: Well actually I think I found the error. the TRUN box is missing a data_offset value, thus the data_offset is considered to be zero from the start of the MOOF box.